# Decrypting RSA with MIHCrypto (OpenSSL-Universal on iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rsa

Hi I've got the a Problem with decrypting using MIHCrypto v0.3.2. These are my lines of code:

```
NSString *encrypted_text = @"BdhFH0sd7e9DExiCd50Ykh4spm2BX126skjJ1o8HHjKsN+J7r9IoI9kbB9AAacEpJsAfyesiJsq5gDBhQtcNbB6l88aSgPrEoVwR9ilzuzVcv1q3J1dxs4uIEMuhzoWT+R8//dD2jDdXPyFsdGWJc10CEizPFKpmy2jWhvU8CVs=";
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *privateKeyPath= [myBundle pathForResource:@"rsa_1024_priv" ofType:@"pem"];    
NSData *privateKeyData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:privateKeyPath];
MIHRSAPrivateKey *privateKey = [[MIHRSAPrivateKey alloc] initWithData:privateKeyData];
NSError *decryptionError = nil;

// decryption
NSData *encData = [encrypted_text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *decryptedEncData = [privateKey decrypt:encData error:&decryptionError];
NSString* decryptedText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedEncData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // iOS 7+, by iOS Core API

if(decryptionError){
    DDLogDebug(@"error: %@",[encryptionError localizedDescription]);
}
DDLogDebug(@"decrypted: %@",decryptedEncData);
```

The problem is debugged here:

error: OpenSLL internal error! (Code=67522668,Description=error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len)

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

Using shorter Blocks of Data!

Background (posted by Hohl - [here](https://github.com/hohl/MIHCrypto/issues/24)):

> Using RSA with large blocks of data seems to be a common issue. Some
>   wrappers handle this by splitting the data into smaller blocks and
>   encrypting every block separately. But since RSA isn't intended to
>   encrypt large blocks of data this won't be implemented in this wrapper.
>   (Better combine RSA with something like AES if you need features of
>   both worlds.)